# Rename recursively files ending with extension '.mpeg' with Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have found a command to rename all files extensions recursively in a directory to another extension but what I'd like to do is to change their names instead of their extensions...
Here is the code I use (it does not work)

```
find . -type f -name "*.mpeg" -exec rename -v 's/*.mpeg$/' video.mepg '{} \;
```

Thank you for any constructive reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ./ -type f -name \*.mpeg -exec rename -v 's/^(.*)\/.*.mpeg$/$1\/video.mpeg/' {} \;
```

This will rename the file portion to video.mpg, but leave the directory structure the same.

Here is the result:

```
ubuntu:~/stackoverflow$ find ./ -type f -name \*.mpeg -exec rename -v 
's/^(.*)\/.*.mpeg$/$1\/video.mpeg/' {} \;
./dir1/dir2/dir3/test.mpeg renamed as ./dir1/dir2/dir3/video.mpeg
./dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/test.mpeg renamed as 
./dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/video.mpeg
./dir1/dir2/test.mpeg renamed as ./dir1/dir2/video.mpeg
./dir1/test.mpeg renamed as ./dir1/video.mpeg
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried the piece of code you gave me. There are no error but it didn't work...
I think it's because the $1 matches only one directory deep ? Shouldn't it be like ^((.*)\/)*.*.mpg ?

Comment: And why use .mpg instead of .mpeg ?

Comment: It does work.  I tried it myself before sending it.  Just change the mpg to mpeg.